# Using \ as a literal exactly before \n in a string in printf

Tags: c, escaping, character

I'm stuck there because I can't use both at the same time:
 printf("   /\n");

You might get an idea what I'm trying to do :)
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to print a single backslash?

Comment: @Mohit M Do you mean  printf(" \\\n");?

Comment: Yes I do. I want to make a triangle by printing those aligned printf statements.

Comment: `\ ` starts an escape sequence. If the character following `\ ` does not match any of the defined escape sequences, the character is printed literally. Since `\ ` is not a defined escape sequence character, two backslashes will print one backslash.

Comment: Read about [Escape Sequences in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/escape-sequences-c/).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: `\\` is a defined escape sequence, per C 2018 6.4.4.4 3. `\` followed by any defined escape sequence is not defined by the C standard, and, per footnote 79 “the result is not a token and a diagnostic is required.”

Comment: @PaulOgilvie \\ _is_ a defined escape sequence. All valid escape sequences are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*I want to make a triangle by printing those aligned `printf` statements.*"

I think what you want is something like that:

```
printf("/\\\n");
```

Output:

```
/\
```

(Note: The empty line is intended)

[Online example](https://godbolt.org/z/ahH8ud)

Read from left to right, The first two `\` (`\\`) denote the `\` character. The third `\` belongs to the newline character (`\n`).

Answer (score 3):

You could print the single backslash before a newline in the following way -

```
printf("Hi\\\nHello");
```

Output :

```
Hi\
Hello
```

The first backslash will be ignored, the second one will be printed and then the newline character will be printed. `\` is used for declaration of an escape sequence. You could also use backslash in a similar way if you want to print other characters like `"` using `printf("\"");` .

---

> Using \ as a literal exactly before \n in a string in printf

```
printf("\\\n");
```

Output :

```
\
```

Hope this solves the issue !

---

Edit :

**Here's your triangle :)** -

```
printf("   /\\\n  /  \\\n /    \\\n/      \\\n--------");
```

Output :

```
   /\
  /  \
 /    \
/      \
--------
```

You could also do it using loops though, which would be much better than this.

Comment: You could use the `_` character instead of `-` to draw the underline. This would look better.

Comment: And I just knew we cannot accept more than one answer, including yours, both being correct :(

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Triangle looks a bit disconnected using `_`. User preference though :)

Comment: @Abhishek -> `printf("   /\\\n  /  \\\n /    \\\n/______\\");`.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yes, perfect !!

Comment: @MohitM You can accept Abhishek's answer, if you want to. He probably needs it more than me.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Or you could just upvote mine. That  would unlock my next privilege :]